# jQuery 1.4 live event, root elements

Tags: jquery

How can I specify root element (which is default page document) in live function in jQuery 1.4 (like in delegate function in 1.4.3+)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function by default gets attached to the root element(`document`)

From Docs

> This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the
>   document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers
>   when content is dynamically added to a page. See the discussion of
>   direct versus delegated events in the .on() method for more
>   information.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Is it possible to change default root element of live function? For example writing my own that uses jQuery live function but add also specified root element?